# How do I properly weight an uneven (spacing) distribution of the numbers?

Tags: mean, weights, range

I have a set of numbers (depths actually) and I need to take the mean of another variable over these depths. For example, take the mean of temperature over a range of depths, however these depths are not evenly spaced. How should I weight them properly to make sure I am keeping into account the uneven spacing of the numbers before taking the average of temperature over these range of depths?

The numbers are:

```
 5.02159 ,  15.07854 ,  25.16046 ,  35.27829 ,  45.44776 ,  55.691494,
        66.041985,  76.54591 ,  87.27029 ,  98.31118 , 109.806175, 121.9519  ,
       135.02855 , 149.43373 , 165.72845 , 184.69746 , 207.42545
```

The first 6 values have an approximate difference of ~10, but how would I take into account the spacing difference between 207.42545 and 184.69746 where the difference is ~28.